# how to solve crashing of apps in android due to memory error which is mostly a case in larger apps with lot of images and other resources

Tags: android

how to solve crashing of apps in android due to memory error which is mostly a case in larger apps with lot of images and other resources.

Comment: I Solved this problem using android:largeHeap="true" in application tag in AndroidManifest.xml

 <application
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:largeHeap="true">
 </application>

Comment: I think you need to reduce image size as most as possible. Each screen size should have specify resolution. Please refer to http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html to optimization your app memory

Comment: @tankrishna this is not the best solution. You should start with optimizing your algorithms, and if doesn't help, only then use this option

Comment: yes i have scaled it down but that doesnt solve the issues as iam using png images as i need to have transparent background behind the images so that i can use it in my layout. png images take lot of space i realised. Also, its a tablet version too much scaling down of images is of no use as you see since it will create problems for larger screen sizes of tablets.Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this type of crash issues if more images are there we need to use **ImageLoader** class, once if if loads from URL it will save it in cache and 2nd time it will load from cache... It will solve most of crash issues and it will work as a lazy loading also..  so it may help us.. sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bitmaps in your app? They use a lot of memory and you will have to optimize their size by scaling them down. The official android website has a great tutorial for this:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/

Comment: the moment a drawable png image was added the app used to crash at various points.iam using it in xml to set backgrounds a 'png' image due to its size the app crashes at various points. if i choose jpeg or so iam unable to have a transparent background for the image.
Thank You.

Comment: I need to use it in layouts xml and most of the images need to be png format due to transparency factor so i cant have scaling each of them down through code and it doesnt solve the issue as for larger screen size tablets these images will appear small.